# how to write xpath for this below situation

Tags: selenium, testing, xpath

I have the elements, highlighted in image :

[image]

The xpath for the list is `//div[@class='list-group formsFilteredList']//a[@class='list-group-item']`, but I need the text of that `a` tag. The text of that are changes dynamically. So I cannot use `text contains` method

Comment: Do you want to get each link text or you want to use text content of `<a>` in `XPath` expression? What is wrong with your `XPath`? Is there any exceptions?

Answer (score 4):

**Try this:**

```
//div[@class='list-group formsFilteredList']//a[@class='list-group-item']/text()
```

Comment: This syntax is not supported by `Selenium`

Comment: Thanks man. Its working. //div[@class='list-group formsFilteredList']//a[@class='list-group-item']/text()

Comment: @Prakashnehru, If this solution is working for you then `accept` the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could find the element by class name instead of xpath but there are several elements with the same class name so what you could do is get the elements into a list and work with them from there:

```
    List<WebElement> lstElements = driver.findElements(By.className("list-group-item"));
```

Then if you know where in the list the element is that you want to use, you can specify the index. For example if you want to click the second item in the list you'd do this:

```
    lstElements.get(1).click();
```

If you want to do something with each of the items in turn then iterate through them in a for loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < lstElements.size(); i++ ) {
        System.out.println("List item text: " + lstElements.get(i).getText());
    }
```